# Openbox overhead is similar to that with gnome-panel

Tags: performance, gnome-panel, openbox

I just installed [openbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox) via `sudo apt-get install openbox`. It already has `obconf`, btw.

I noticed that when I logged into my openbox session instead of the one I usually use (`gnome-panel` and NOT Ubuntu 2D or one of the high overhead environments) and checked via `htop`, I found that a similar amount of RAM was being occupied (~600 MB or so) with openbox or gnome-panel.

What gives? Openbox looks lighter but it certainly isn't any different. Obviously the same daemons etc would run in both environments as they share the same folders.

Is `gnome-panel` as good as openbox then?

### Edit:

The comparison of memory used is quite similar and the gain isn't large by any means (by using openbox)
`htop` output with `gnome-panel`

[image]

`htop` output with `openbox` session

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include actual data? Which specific process do you attribute to openbox overhead? IMO, a fairer way to test would be to compare RAM "occupied" on a pure Lubuntu installation and not on a "hybrid" system that has a variety of desktops even though only one is selected at login.

Comment: It's a bit unclear but even I don't know how to output to a file rather than a screenshot. Anyway, assuming things are sorted with RAM hogs at the top, I'm not seeing anything that's specific to openbox near the top. Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding your issue.